# Making a header with 2 selections on left and right, and a logo in the center

Tags: html, css

**Experience with this code**
Im a student, and this site, started as a school work. I dont have much experience with it, but im ready to learn if needs to be.

**Main problem**
I would really like to make a header like this:

[image]

I don't really know what to code for making something like that, since I tried my best, but it wont work. Down here, the code:

```css
header {
  background-color: #d60000;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -21px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navleft {}

ul#navright {
  float: right;
}

img#logo {
  padding-top: 24px;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Meltix">
        <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" width="200" height="40" alt="Logo Meltix YT" /></a>
    </h1>
    <ul id="navleft">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="video.html">Video</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="navright">
      <li>
        <a href="contenuti.html">Contenuti & Link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="info.html">Informazioni</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

With a system like that, the header does this work:

[image]

Comment: Flexbox (display `flex`) and grids (`display `grid`) is useful for dealing with many previous difficult layouts without resorting to workarounds, JavaScript layout engines (with all the downsides that can come with), etc. Definitely worth learning, and hopefully included in any web course now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I use flexbox for stuff like this. For a great explanation look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  background-color:#d60000;
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
}

li{
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60x60"></li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: @KarthickSrinivasan seems that your method works more than the other ones. But i dont know ho you see your coding example, but the two selection in the left and the right are placed in a list method. I dont know why, but even editing the with a separated inline function it doesnt work.

Comment: @Meltix I do not know if you are responding to me or the other guy. But what exactly is the problem? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry for the ping mess, im still trying to learn how to mention people. But anyway, what i said to Karthick Srinivasan is, that his code is basically correct, because is almost like my request, but in his code, the links, link 1,2,3 and 4, are in a list layout. What i wanted to be is a inline layout, not list. Look at my images, that is the layout that im looking for. Also, i said that i tried to wrote in, a separated inline function so maybe it could be correct, but it doesnt work. Also tried your code, and it doesnt work as well.

Comment: If the above code does not work for you then you are most likey doing something wrong. Or something else in your code is overwriting the above code. My example is pretty much the same as your images in your question. Maybe edit the question with all the code you have so we can see if something is being overwritten.

Comment: i just tried again your code. It seems that yours works almost perfectly. I have to fix something, into my code. I dont know why but the logo that i put is not in the center of the header. Also, the links are attached to the top of the page, but i probably need to fix with a padding-top.

Comment: @Meltix Double check that your image is not wierdly setup. You can fix the text to the top either with padding or line-height. if the image is proper you can try margin: 0 auto;

Comment: thank you very much! im having trouble with the logo, thought... is there any way that i can contact you, please?

Comment: What is your prefered platform for contacting me ? And what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: If you want, we contact on Discord, Hangouts or Twitter. Im having trouble with my logo, which as the code says, is an image

Comment: @Meltix Alright, shoot me a link and ill join your discord

Comment: Name: itsMeltix#0928

Comment: @Meltix You turned off friend requests for some reason here is mine: GrannyWithA50Cal#8247

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using `display:flex` check below working snippet

```css
header {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 60px;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

header ul li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li><img src="" alt="image goes here"></li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added container with flex box property in css.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  background-color: #d60000;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -21px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navleft {}

ul#navright {
  float: right;
}

img#logo {
  padding-top: 24px;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="navleft">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="video.html">Video</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/Meltix">
      <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" width="200" height="40" alt="Logo Meltix YT" /></a>
  </h1>

  <ul id="navright">
    <li>
      <a href="contenuti.html">Contenuti & Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="info.html">Informazioni</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your HTML the same, you can to do the following:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav h1 {
  order: 1;
}

#navleft {
  order: -1
}
```